# Data dependent dropdown

Tags: visualforce-component

Our Contacts object has a custom field called is_prospect__c (checkbox).  We've been asked to alter the behaviour of the New/Edit Task's standard page so that the Type dropdown shows a different list of items if the Contact is a prospect compared to when they are not.  Hope that makes sense.

One suggestion was to use a custom component.  So my first question is if this is a sensible approach?  If not, what do you recommend?

If a custom component is the correct way, how do we make one appear when in New/Edit mode?  We can get a 'HelloWorld' component to appear when just viewing a task without any problem. Is this a restriction on custom components that they do not work in New/Edit mode or are we missing something?

Comment: Have you considered doing this declaratively with dependent picklists instead of a checkbox? It would be far easier, cheaper (both in terms of upfront cost and technical debt), and quite possibly better.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply but I didn't realise that it was possible to do this when the custom field that is controlling the dropdown list is on a different object (contact) from the task.  I'll read up on dependent picklists to see if they are up to the job. Thanks again.

Comment: I've had a look & it seems to me that dependent picklists only work if the controlling field & dependent field are on the same object which in this specific case they are not.  Am I missing something @greenstork?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that they were on separate objects. You are correct that it would not work then without apex/visualforce.

Comment: For future reference it looks to me as though you cannot do what I wanted without replacing the standard page with your own custom built visualforce page.  Alternatively you could place a before insert, before update trigger on Task which does the validation & writes an error if the user has picked an invalid combination e.g. `for (Task task in Trigger.new){ if (_condition_){ task.addError('Your custom error message')}`